# Implement reusable custom on click listener for custom view

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I have a custom view (button) when I click on it I want to do some animation before.

```
mycustomButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {   
           //FIRST
           startAnimation()

           //THEN
           //... call what you want ...
        }
});
```

This code works BUT I want to use the same custom view for many app and I don't want to copy the same code for each app so I create a module(contains):

- MyCustomView(Button)
- CustomAnimation
- ...

So I want to use my module for more than one app. And at each time I do the same thing when I click on my custom view:

- First, start animation (the same animation for all app).
- Then, call want I want

How I can implement a custom on click listener when I click on it does an animation before and I want to keep the default on click parameter (View view)

Something like that:

```
mycustomview.setCustomOnClickListener(new MyCustomView.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {   
        //... call what you want ...
    }
});
```

Examples:

App 1:

```
mycustomview.setCustomOnClickListener(new MyCustomView.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {   
        callCalenderActivity();
    }
});
```

App 2:

```
mycustomview.setCustomOnClickListener(new MyCustomView.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {  
        compute(); 
        callOpenGLActivity();
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override setOnClickListener so it saves the listener passed in in a variable.  In your constructor, write a custom OnClickListener that does what you wants, then calls that saved listener.onClick if its not null.  Then use super.setOnClickListener to set your custom click listener.

```
   OnClickListener childListener;

   public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener listener) {
       childListener = listener;
   }

   Constructor() {
       super.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View view) {
               //Do what you want
               if(childListener != null) {
                   childListener.onClick(view);
               }
           }
        });
    }
```